# Not able to create Multiple Attribute in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement to create a DynamoDB table with four Attribute. I am using the following Java program:

```
String tableName = "devtest";

Table table = dynamoDB.createTable(tableName,
                    Arrays.asList(new KeySchemaElement("BIC", KeyType.HASH)), // Sort key
                    Arrays.asList(new AttributeDefinition("BIC", ScalarAttributeType.S),
                        new AttributeDefinition("Tenant", ScalarAttributeType.S),
                        new AttributeDefinition("TenantID", ScalarAttributeType.S),
                        new AttributeDefinition("Destination", ScalarAttributeType.S)),
                    new ProvisionedThroughput(10L, 10L));
table.waitForActive();
System.out.println("Success.  Table status: " + table.getDescription().getTableStatus());
```

I am always getting the following error:

```
Unable to create table: 
Unable to unmarshall exception response with the unmarshallers provided (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: bc0565ac-9d44-4876-934a-b39fbe8ca3f1)
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: It sounds like you may not have the appropriate permissions to create the table

Comment: I have, I am using local host       AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "ap-southeast-2"))
            .build();

Comment: String tableName = "devtest";

Table table = dynamoDB.createTable(tableName,
                    Arrays.asList(new KeySchemaElement("BIC", KeyType.HASH)), // Sort key
                    Arrays.asList(new AttributeDefinition("BIC", ScalarAttributeType.S))
                                           new ProvisionedThroughput(10L, 10L));
                table.waitForActive();
            If I am using above code that tabls is getting successful created

Comment: Can any one help me on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can have only one attribute** `BIC`, because this is your `HASH`. Since you don't have any sort key, local or global secondary indices, you can't define any other attributes.

DynamoDB is **schema-less**, which means that it does not have any per-define structure.